# Announcing a new ros package

Tags: ros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've developed a new ros package and would like to announce its release on the ROS wiki announcements page. How can I?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32841/announcing-a-new-ros-package/) by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 365 on 2012-04-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2012-10-24**:
what is the new package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Send an email to ros-users@code.ros.org

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2012-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3